# Retrieve all video files from all directories of SD card

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard

I'm making a media player. I want to get all videos present in the **sd card**.

If the video is directly available in top directory of **sd card**, it is simple. But what about a video file exists in nested directory structure like

> directory->directory->directory->file.mp4.

How can I search for a file in a nested directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list which can store the location of all the video files present on sd card. Run a loop which will visit every folder and update this array if given file format (in your case video files or .mp4) and add it to array. You can store this list onto persistent storage so as you can read it the next time your application is launched.

Here is sample code which can help you list all files in sdcard

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                    || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif")) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Forgive the code indentation since i am on mobile device.

Comment: this is if a file is in one folder.what if file is inside a folder which is inside many folders.?

Comment: There is a recursive call to the function getfile() if it finds a directory. So this will work for all the files and folder if you call it with argument as path of sdcard eg: listfile("/mnt/sdcard")

Answer (score 1):

With Apache FileUtils:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String path = ...;
String[] extensions = {"mp4", "mov", ...};
Collection<File> allMovies = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), extensions, true);
```

Comment: You have to add the jar or use maven. Download: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Comment: I got the solution the first answer . its easier for me thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

am posting this, maybe it would help some one in need.
as @Jaqen H'ghar said ... i just simplify the code to add the list of the extensions u want to show.

```
File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

        List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();


        String[] extensions = {"apk","mp3","mp4","or what ever extension u want"};
        Collection<File> allMovies = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(String.valueOf(filePath)), extensions, true);


        for (File file: allMovies) {


                fileList.add(file.getName());

        }
```